# Batch color extract to csv standardized

Tags: batch-file, colors, export-to-csv

I'm trying to take a folder full of GIF files and extract the (top 3) main colors of each of them with file name into a csv file for use in optimization software.

I have both windows and linux environments. I figured out this code on linux cmd line.

```
for f in *.gif; do extcolors "$f"; done
```

I thought this would be good enough but I have three issues:
1. Only 3 colors from each enough - because i need it standardized
2. No file name
3. I need specific formatting of the following columns for each line; file name, RGB1, %1, RGB2, %2, RGB3, %3 and I can't figure out how to manipulate the output

If you could help me understand how to access csv writing I could figure most out from there I believe. Thanks!!

Comment: Windows also has a `for` loop that can take wildcards. Check out the output of `for /?`

Comment: Feels like given your extra requirements, and to avoid differing solutions for linux and windows, it might be worth writing the whole thing into a python script using the extcolors module, rather than trying to hack around the commandline version output.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i'd post the solution here - a python code

```
import os, csv
import extcolors

f=open("/home/raz/PycharmProjects/test.csv",'r+')
w=csv.writer(f)
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/raz/PycharmProjects/clr"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.gif'):
            print(filename,extcolors.extract(filename))
            w.writerow([filename,extcolors.extract(filename)])
```